# How to automatically download files from FTP server with PhpStorm?

Tags: ftp, ide, phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

I use a PHP IDE : PhpStorm, for my web project. The problem is I must download each files when I begin to develop.

Is there a solution who allow download files from FTP server automatically when I change file?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I change file"? If you are changing (editing) the file ... then file is already downloaded... right? Or you doing it differently?

Comment: No the file, is not already downloaded.  I must click right on my mouse and click "Deployment" => Download from ftp server.  "When I change file" mean If I use an another file : index.php then style.css for example.

Comment: So .. you are editing `index.php` (for example) which you already have locally .. and want IDE to download some another file (e.g. `style.css`) for you automatically? That's not possible. Either download all and then setup [automatic upload](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm) ... or [edit files remotely](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/04/remote-edit-in-phpstorm-9-eap/) (IDE will download it in background .. so it will never be placed into the actual project)

Comment: Ah okay, how can I have the most recent version of my "index.php" without downloading from ftp server each time ?

Comment: Not possible to do that automatically. This IDE is built with idea that "local code is the source -- remote is just a copy" .. so it can only do automatic upload. The best you can do is to set "Notify about remote changes" before you will be editing local file -- IDE should check if file is different to your current local version and offer to download from remote if it is. BTW -- you can run "Synchroize with Remote" manually -- IDE will give you a list of all files that are different -- OK to use if number of files is relatively small.

Comment: So nobody does a composer install on the dev server and then wants the files downloaded / generated there back in their PhpStorm?